# MeanJS Application Fails to Instantiate AngularJS Module After Being Pushed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, highcharts, meanjs

I am having issues with a MeanJS application which is using highcharts-ng.

The charts work locally, but when I push my project to my development server using git the charts die and I get the following error in angularjs:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module highcharts-ng due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'highcharts-ng' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

In my MeanJS config file I have the following:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = [..., 'highcharts-ng'];
```

In my config/env/all.js file I have defined the following assets:

```
'public/lib/highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework.js',
'public/lib/highcharts-release/highstock-all.js',
'public/lib/highcharts-ng/src/highcharts-ng.js'
```

I can see that these files get loaded on my local machine when viewing the index page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/highcharts-release/highstock-all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/highcharts-ng/src/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
```

When viewing the same page on my development server after doing a 'git push ... ' these highchart JS files are not being loaded.

I can browse to the public/lib directory on my development server and I can see that all the highchart files are there, but for some reason not being loaded, so it's not like it's a problem with git ignore's.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the case sensitivity in src =".."
Because i think your your deployment server is linux server.And your local server is window.

It happen because you deploy and build it with gulp or grunt.?
check node modules path and src path case sensitivity is the issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

You are correct in that the development server is *nix based and my local server is windows based, however, the paths are all lowercase in both instances however so this isn't the issue.

Comment: are you using gulp..?

Comment: Nope. I am not using gulp for anything.

Comment: any other tasks jobs like grunt /gulp..?

Comment: because your depndencies are not loaded on your linux server because of these tasks when you run in deployment on server,,

Comment: I am just using 'grunt' to launch the MEAN application from my local machine while developing it.

Comment: do you make any task in grunt to make scripts to specific location from repository to your src..?

Comment: And its all because of path issue nothing else.
is it case sensitivity or wrong path..

For surity you can check you have the file placed on that location on server or not..

Comment: It's not a path issue. Because like I mentioned in the original question, it is looking for files at:

'public/lib/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js', and when I log in to the development server and cd to this directory, this file DOES exist. (paths match, all completely lowercase so case sensitivity is not an issue).